# AWS codebuild not building my github pull requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, continuous-integration, webhooks, aws-codebuild

I have set up the **AWS codebuild** to my *github repo*, but unfortunately my pull requests are not being built. Only the commits.

According to the **AWS codebuild** [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/aws-codebuild-now-supports-building-github-pull-requests/), the pull request builds should be supported natively.

I have checked the option to run the build whenever the code changes.

**Is this feature supposed to work seamlessly**? I can see github actually sends webhooks upon PR with:

```
X-GitHub-Event: pull_request
```

but nothing happens on **AWS codebuild** side..
how can i troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is pull option checked? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-github-pull-request.html#verification-checks

Comment: sure, there is not "pull option" only "webhook" option. and it is checked.
i have specified the filter branch to be master,
and the target of pull request is also MASTER.
when i remove the filter branch the build actually starts fine.
but i want this build to be only on pull requests to MASTER branch.. 
@Creeper123

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at the response you're getting from back from AWSCodeBuild this should be in **`Repository -> Settings -> Webhooks -> https://codebuild.#{region}.amazonaws.com/webhooks`**. From here you can scroll to the bottom of the page and look at Recent Deliveries.

Could you let me know the latest output from a PR.

John

Comment: i am getting HTTP 200 with : `{"response":"No build triggered for specified branch","statusCode":200}`

Comment: i have specified the filter branch to be master, and the target of pull request is also MASTER. when i remove the filter branch the build actually starts fine. but i want this build to be triggered only on pull requests to MASTER branch

Comment: I am pretty sure it is AWS problem when they check the filter of the source branch (HEAD) instead of the  target branch (BASE), i have opened a support ticket.